# File's App Icon No Longer Displays

Tags: applications, icon, file

I'm a developer and use a framework called "JUCE," and the associated application with JUCE is the Projucer.  Projucer uses .jucer files.  Previously, the app icon would show up inline with the file name, much as a Word .doc has a little graphic next to the filename.  I'm unsure of what changed, but all I see is a blank page, instead of the app icon.  This has stumped me for months.  Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]